# Trouble with AngularFire (Firebase) and Authenticating with Routers

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, ngroute

I'm working on an Angular web app that is using Firebase to authenticate the user when they login or register. I want to restrict going to the /dashboard url unless they're logged in. I tried following Firebase's docs, but I'm coming up with errors.

I think where I'm having problems was making my controller code work with the one provided. I kept getting the error "Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- currentAuth", so I just took out their controller code for now.

Any help would be great!

Here's the doc link: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers

And my code:

**ROUTER CONFIG**

```
var app = angular.module('maggsLashes', ['ngRoute', 'ui.calendar', 'firebase']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
     .when('/dashboard', {
      templateUrl: 'app/templates/dashboardTmpl.html',
      controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
          // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
          // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
          return Auth.$requireAuth();
        }]
      }
    })
```

**DASHBOARD CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $location) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://maggslashes.firebaseio.com/");

  var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

//   app.controller("AccountCtrl", ["currentAuth", function(currentAuth) {
//   // currentAuth (provided by resolve) will contain the
//   // authenticated user or null if not logged in
// }]);

  // console.log(auth);
  console.log("Matt is pretty much awesome");

  ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
    if (authData) {
      console.log("User is authenticated w uid:", authData);

    }
    else {
      console.log("client sucks");
    }
  });

  $scope.logOut = function() {
    $location.path('/');
    $scope.apply();
    ref.unauth();
    console.log(authData.uid);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see what may be at least on issue.  In your router, you refer to "Auth" but do not see your code for that service/factory, so it's possible you don't have that set up. Note that "Auth" is a custom factory.

not you need this somewhere in your code:

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",


function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-sandbox.firebaseio.com", "example3");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
])
```

Also, can you provide the errors you're receiving?

Wayne